# regex to match any filename mask

Tags: regex, file, sequence, mask

I have to write a regex that will match any sequence filename masks, eg:

Three test cases:
`object.scrn_1-2_0006` - should match `object.scrn_1-2`
`object.scrn0006` - should match `object.scrn`
`object0006` - should match `object`

where `0006` is the number of file in sequence, from `0000` to any number.

Optionally the second expression should match this number.
While it's pretty easy to match the second and third I've found it pretty hard to match the first.

I used the following regex to match name:
`[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+[_\-\.]?\d*`

and this one to match number:
`[_\-\.]?[123456789][0-9]*\b`

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: isn't it the first example matches `object.scrn_1-2_` ?

Answer (score 0):

/^(.+)\d{4)$/ should do what you need in case of **object.scrn_1-2_0006**, object.scrn_1-2_ will be in the 1st register

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single regex to match and catch the pieces you need. For instance, you can use

```
(^.*)(\d{4}$)
```

`(^.*)` catches every character at the start of the string;

`(\d{4}$)` catches the 4 digits (`\d` means one numeric character and `{4}` makes it exactly 4 digits).

The first caught group is everything before the last 4 digits and the second caught group contains the 4 digits.

If there can be variable number of digits, simply turn the `{4}` to `+`

```
(^.*)(\d+$)
```

Comment: The main problem is that there could be more or less than 4 digits at the end.

Comment: @user1598259 Then simply change the `{4}` to `+`. I added that bi to my answer.

Comment: @user1598259 It will match the whole name, but _capture_ the specific bits and put them in a list or array, depending on the language you're using.

Comment: @user1598259 haha, awesome then :)